# Aptana Advanced Search Dialog

Tags: aptana

In Aptana Studio 3, there are two ways to search in a document you're working on.

1. The 'Find Bar' at the bottom.
2. Opens a Dialog up identical to the find dialog in Eclipse

When I press ctrl+F, it opens the find bar. Though, I want it to open the dialog, which I've done before, but cannot figure out how to do again.

How can I do that?

P.S. I am **NOT** talking about the file search that opens with ctrl+H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a preference for that.

Go to `Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Find Bar` and un-check the 'Use custom find bar...' option.